# toaster warning message box not displaying properlly

Tags: css, angular, toast

I am using toaster notification service to my angular project but only issue i am facing with toaster.warning method which is related to the css actually it doesn't look well but toaster for success and error notification works.
This how warning toaster in orange color looks like ,

[image]

And the code which i am using to display this message :

```
this.toastr.warning("No Headcount data found for clarityIds", "Headcount", {
  timeOut: 6000,
  closeButton: true
});
```

Comment: can you do inspect element these toster and see, if except color all the css should be same. It seems something is overriding your .warning class .

Comment: I cannot see that.. Is there any way to see the default css of toaster ?